# how to redirect to external webpage in new tab?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

working with asp.net mvc in view.
how to redirect to external webpage in new tab?

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Paypal", "HowItWorksRedirect", null, new { @class = "Paypal" })%>

 public ActionResult HowItWorksRedirect()
        {
            return Redirect("https://www.paypal-deutschland.de/sicherheit/schutzprogramme.html");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't pass this to a controller action, because you're not linking to within your own website. Just write the markup manually. If you need to re-use it, put it in a section or partial view:

```
<a href="https://www.paypal-deutschland.de/sicherheit/schutzprogramme.html" target="_blank" class="Paypal">Paypal</a>
```